# AWS BitFusion instance ImportError("Cuda not found. Cannot unpickle CudaNdarray")

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pickle

I am trying to unpickle a CudaNdarray, and I am getting an import error. I know that I need to be on a machine with a GPU, so I searched around and found [this BitFusion ec2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01B52CMSO/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-11&qid=1457533592503) which supposedly has GPU support as well as cuda. I downloaded all the dependencies for my code but I am getting this:

```
File "predictor.py", line 112, in <module>
    predict = loadModel(filePath = '2_21_dim20000PREDICT113000.save')
  File "predictor.py", line 91, in loadModel
    model = pickle.load(file2open, encoding='latin1')
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/type.py", line 591, in CudaNdarray_unpickler
    raise ImportError("Cuda not found. Cannot unpickle CudaNdarray")
ImportError: Cuda not found. Cannot unpickle CudaNdarray
```

Here is the code I have (Python3):

```
import os
import sys
import pickle
from random import shuffle
from copy import copy

def loadModel(filePath):
    file2open = open(filePath, 'rb')
    model = pickle.load(file2open, encoding='latin1')
    b.encode("latin1")
    file2open.close()
    return zlib.decompress(b)

predict = loadModel(filePath = '2_21_dim20000PREDICT113000.save')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple things you can try:

A) Ensure the Cuda toolkit is installed:

```
conda list | grep cudatoolkit
```

If you do not see it try the following:

```
conda install cudatoolkit

python
>>> from numbapro import cuda
>>> cuda.is_available()
True
>>> cuda.__file__
'/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/snowflakes/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numba/cuda/__init__.py'
```

B) Do you need to import the CUDA package under Theano?

```
python
>>> from theano.sandbox import cuda
>>>cuda.cuda_path
'/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/snowflakes/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda'
```